Configure vcalendar default hour to 00
I'm using v-calendar datepicker 3.0
with configuration:
<DatePicker v-model="date" :mode="mode" :locale="locale" is24hr :model-config="modelConfig" @dayclick="pickDate" @input="pickDate" ref="calendar" @daykeydown="onKeydown" :popover="popoverOptions">

When in DateTime mode is seleced date , hour is automatically added according local time, example 11:00. Is there possible to configure that it is by default 00:00 ?

This is what I expected it to do, thnx @imhvost for initial code sample:
<template>
  <v-date-picker is24hr v-model="date" mode="datetime" @dayclick="dayclick" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, nextTick } from "vue";
import "v-calendar/dist/style.css";

// Initialize date as null by default
const date = ref(null);

const dayclick = async (day) => {
  await nextTick();
  const selectedDate = new Date(day.date);
  selectedDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  date.value = selectedDate;
};
</script>

Live demo

Use @dayclick event. I checked - it works:
<script setup>
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue';

const date = ref(new Date());
const dayclick = async day => {
  await nextTick();
  date.value = day.date;
};
</script>

<template>
  <VDatePicker
    v-model="date"
    mode="dateTime"
    is24hr
    @dayclick="dayclick"
  />
</template>


That is for limiting user input. ref. https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/releases/tag/v3.0.0

Ok, I think I understand what you want. Answer updated.

for v2 was playing around with this one, but time is autofilled after date select https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-burnell-rk5h2j?file=/src/App.vue
